# Allow optional parameters in Joi without specifying them

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I'm fairly new to using Joi to validate request payloads in hapi. My question is the following. I have this defined route:

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/foo/bar',
    config: {
      description: 'foo.bar',
      handler: handlers.foo,
      auth:false,
      tags: ['api'],
      validate: {
        payload: {
          email : Joi.string().required(),
          password : Joi.string().required(),
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Email and password are my required properties. However, i would like to allow other properties without having to specify them all. for example:

```
{
  email: foo@bar.com,
  password: fooPass,
  name: myName,
  surname: mySurname
}
```

Is there a way to do it with Joi?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can set `allowUnknown` to `true` in `options`:

```
validate: {
  payload: {
    email : Joi.string().required(),
    password : Joi.string().required(),
  },
  options: {
    allowUnknown: true
  }
}
```

The `options` parameter is passed to [Joi](http://github.com/hapijs/joi) on validation.

Answer (score 5):

For current version of Joi (v15.1.0), while doing

`Joi.validate(value, schema, options)`

set `allowUnknown: true`

into the `options` object.

**Reference**:

https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v15.1.0/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback